# Is it safe to call `Py_DecRef` on an object created before the last Py_Initialize?

Tags: python, python-c-api

Assuming all participating modules correctly handle `Py_Finalize`, does C API allow this:

```
Py_Initialize();
...
PyObject* myObj = PyObject_Call(simple_class, empty_tuple, NULL);
Py_Finalize();
...
Py_Initialize();
Py_DecRef(myObj); // <--- is this safe by design?
```

#### Narrowed down example that crashes

```c
Py_Initialize();
PyObject* builtins = PyEval_GetBuiltins();
PyObject* iter = PyDict_GetItemString(builtins, "iter");

Py_IncRef(iter);

Py_Finalize();

// ----- new run starts, iter should still be alive

Py_Initialize();

Py_DecRef(iter);

Py_Finalize(); // fails inside PyGC_Collect -> validate_list
```

#### Background (OLD, before narrowing down the problem)

I am debugging 3.9+ support in https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

The issue I originally got is `validate_list` from `gcmodule.c` fails at

```c
assert(prev == GC_PREV(head));
```

In debugging this, I sprinkled my code with calls to `validate_list`, and found
that the assertion fails in the following scenario:

```c
Py_Initialize();
...
PyObject* myObj = PyObject_Call(simple_class, args, NULL);
Py_Finalize();
...
Py_Initialize();
...
validate_list(gc.generations[2],
              collecting_clear_unreachable_clear); // OK
Py_DecRef(myObj);
validate_list(gc.generations[2],
              collecting_clear_unreachable_clear); // EXPLOSION
```

Now I have not yet tried to narrow down the steps further, because I realized
that I am unsure about the question in the title. E.g. is this use of `myObj`
supported by embedding API in general, or is this expected, that after
reinitializing the runtime `Py_DecRef` on old objects would break GC?

In my scenario `simple_class` is defined in Python as inheriting from `object`, e.g. it is a heap type created by Python runtime from Python code:

```py
class SimpleClass(object):
  def __init__(self, type, tb):
    self.type = type
    self.traceback = tb
```

`type` and `tb` are values you get from `PyErr_Fetch` when list ends.

The reason why I have to `Py_DecRef` after `Py_Finalize` + `Py_Initialize` is that `myObj` actually gets collected by a different GC (.NET).

Comment: I am pretty sure, most python object become invalid after finalize. For example part of their memory is from python’s memory manager, which was returned to OS at that point. You probably could create objects, which could outlive python interpreter, but for normal objects this is not the case.